# Telegram bot in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, bots, telegram

Currently, I'm doing a currency converter bot on telegram using python 3.

```
def on_callback_query(msg):
    query_id, from_id, query_data = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='callback_query')
    print('Callback Query:', query_id, from_id, query_data)

url = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=SGD&symbols="
symbols = query_data
response = requests.get(url + symbols)
data = response.json()
print(data)

if(query_data == 'SGD'):
    bot.sendMessage(from_id, data)

elif (query_data == 'EUR'):
    bot.sendMessage(from_id, data)
```

The data here will out {'rates': {'EUR': 0.62177}, 'base': 'SGD', 'date': '2017-09-18'} in my telegram chat. Is there anyway to beautify the output, i.e. take out the curly brackets and quotes?

Comment: tried to use split in-built functions, however

'dict' object has no attribute 'split' error is found

Answer (score 1):

This format named JSON and you can parse it as an object and simply print it with a custom format.
See [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_python_example.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The result is in JSON format which is then converted to a dictionary, you can extract each element from the dictionary and use it to create a better format.
You can write in any format you like, here's an example

```
if(query_data == 'SGD'):
    result = "Rates in EUR: {}\nBase: {}\nDate: {}".format(data['rates']['EUR'], data['base'], data['date'])
    bot.sendMessage(from_id, result)

if(query_data == 'EUR'):
    result = "Rates in SGD: {}\nBase: {}\nDate: {}".format(data['rates']['SGD'], data['base'], data['date'])
    bot.sendMessage(from_id, result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's almost definitely a more efficient way of doing this than the way I did it, but it works.

```
str(output).replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("'","")
```